# I want to change a column value if the cell in the column match specific test

Tags: excel, vba

I did following coding but I want to set range to be range("E:E") because I don't know how many rows will be. However it doesn't work.

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("E1:E800")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value = "Yes" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you define "it doesn't work",  which part of your code doesn't work. Remember you have forgotten to specify a worksheet. Try `With .... End with` and use you worksheets `CodeName`. And about the whole column.... Don't! There are multiple posts on here and through Google that will show you how to find the last row of a column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post a question, try to give: Input sample, expected output sample, what did you try and your research. If you have non empty cells, this range can be defined by `ActiveSheet.Range (E:E).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just process the used range in Col E you can do something like this:

```
Set SrchRng = Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: I would definitely include a worksheet reference (which probably is the cause of "it doesn't work") =)

Answer (score 0):

i prefer such style.

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet 'change to needed
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, 5) = "Yes" Then
                .Cells(i, 5 + 1) = .Cells(i, 5)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you decide to go this route you might want to include the dots in front of Cells to make sure you actually work through the specified sheet (which active sheet is really not the best option)

Comment: thanks for dots, forget about it. Active sheet - for change.
Prefer work without ranges, when possible.